# Detecting words with exactly X uppercase letters

Tags: c#, regex, match

I've been thinking hard about this one, but can't find a solution with my current knowledge.

I'm trying to detect words in a sentence that have exactly, lets say 2 for example's sake, uppercase letters at any position with the rest being lowercase.

So HEllo, HellO or heLLo would get matched but Hello or HEllO wouldn't.

Comment: I would use a simple for loop instead of RegEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, if you want a RegEx :)

Here is the same for 3 letters.  You can change the integer in the pattern count to any number you prefer.

```
        string strTester = "AaaaAA";

        var results = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(strTester,"(.*[A-Z]{1}.*){3,}");
        var occuranceCount = results.Count;

        if (occuranceCount >= 1 ) {
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of writing my Regex that way, after modyfing it for my specific needs (`.` was a bit too large), it did the trick.
thefourtheye's solution would have worked as well, but pattern length might have gotten a bit too long in some cases.

And the regex choice is mostly because I've been trying for a while to get better at it and finally got a project where I get many different matching problems to solve.

Comment: Glad it helped!  I also love RegEx, being a bit "old school".  It is still very powerful for data validation.  I have to note that lambda stuff is pretty cool....I'm a bit behind on .Net anymore.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done without Regex and with Lambda, reads pretty nicely.

```
string sentence = "This IS a SEntence";

var wordCount = sentence.Split(new char[] { ' ' })
  .Where(word => word.Count(letter => char.IsUpper(letter)) == 2)
  .Count();

Console.WriteLine(wordCount );
Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

> 2

Answer (score 2):

This RegEx would work

```
^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*$
```

From the beginning of the string, match 0 or more lowercase letters, then the first uppercase letter, and then 0 or more lowercase letters and then second Upper case letter and then 0 or more lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think that a combination of `Char.IsUpper` and `System.Linq` will enable a more elegant and maintainable solution -

```
public static class Word
{
    public static bool HasUppercaseLetter(string word, int howManyUpper = 1)
    {
        return word.Count(char.IsUpper) == howManyUpper;
    }

    public static int HowManyWordsHaveUppercaseLetters(string sentence, 
        int howManyUpper = 1)
    {
        var words = sentence.Split(new[] {' '});
        return words.Count(w => HasUppercaseLetter(w, howManyUpper));
    } 
}
```

Additionally, here are some unit tests to prove that the the aforementioned function works against your sample input

```
[TestFixture]
public class WordTests
{
    [TestCase("HellO", Result = true)]
    [TestCase("heLLo", Result = true)]
    [TestCase("HEllO", Result = false)]
    [TestCase("Hello,", Result = false)]
    public bool HasTwoUppercaseLetters(string word)
    {
        return Word.HasUppercaseLetter(word, 2);
    }

    [Test]
    public void HasTwoWordsWithTwoUppercaseLetters()
    {
        // Inpsired by Erik Philips
        Assert.True(
            Word.HowManyWordsHaveUpperCaseLetters("This IS a SEntence", 2) == 2);
    }
}
```